# IE resubmitting authentication header on failed login

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, basic-authentication

I am supporting an application that uses basic authentication and is working mostly correctly, but on IE it is sending the authentication header twice when the authentication attempt fails.

```
var authorizationBasic = btoa(stUsername + ":" + stPassword);
loginRequest.open("POST", stUrl, true,stUsername, stPassword);
loginRequest.setRequestHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic "+authorizationBasic);
loginRequest.withCredentials = true;

loginRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (loginRequest.readyState == 4){
     ... some logic....
   }
}
loginRequest.send();
```

This code is working fine on other browsers, but IE uses 2 authentication attempts every time the user makes the call.

When I get to the first call in the onreadystate it already has sent the duplicated headers. Anyone knows how to fix this?
Thank you,

**Update 1:** checking the expected behavior the browser is supposed to send an opening request without the credentials:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication

And on the 401 error is supposed to answer back with the credentials, this is the behavior I'm seeing on Chrome using fiddler, but IE sends the credentials on both requests causing the double hit to the login attempts counter. Is this a bug, or is there any way to modify this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching I was able to find a hacked solution to this, please don't judge me for it and let me know if you find something better. I still think this is an IE bug and it might get fixed in the future.

```
var authorizationBasic = btoa(stUsername + ":" + stPassword);
document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache", false); (1)
loginRequest.open("HEAD", vUrl, true,"whatever","blah"); (2)
loginRequest.setRequestHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "x-Basic "+authorizationBasic);
loginRequest.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+authorizationBasic); (3)
loginRequest.withCredentials = true;

loginRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (loginRequest.readyState == 4){
     if (loginRequest.status == 200) {


        var dummyReq = fGetRequest();
        dummyReq.open("HEAD", vUrl, false,stUsername, stPassword);
        dummyReq.setRequestHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "x-Basic "+authorizationBasic); (4)
        window.location.href = vUrl;
```

Here's how it works:

1. This is the part that I hate the most, it clears authentication information of ALL open sessions on IE, have to use it with care, when I wasn't using it I was getting weird results, so I'm trying to modify my log out procedure to avoid the use of this instruction.
2. IE sends this username and password on the first request (the one that is supposed to have no authentication information), you can put whatever fake information here, just be sure you don't use a real username. If we don't send this information we'll get the login prompt.
3. Here goes the real authentication information, the status of the request on the readystatechange event will depend on this information.
4. After you have checked credentials do the regular login requests, if you don't do this you will get the login prompt.

I'm still using the regular authentication method with all other browsers. If you know of a better solution, please let me know.